# How to pass data through a spark mapper without modelling it in the parameter class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I need to do stateful processing of dataframe rows. To do that I need to create a bean or case class that models the data necessary for the stateful processing. I would like to hang on to other data in the dataframe for use after the stateful processing without modelling it in the case class. How can this be done?

In stateless processing we can sort of stay in DataFrame land by using UDFs but we do not have that option here.

Here's what I tried:

```
package com.example.so

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.{GroupState, GroupStateTimeout, OutputMode}

case class WibbleState() // just a placeholder

case class Wibble
(
  x: String,
  y: Int,
  data: Row // data I don't want to model in the case class
)

object PartialModelization {

  def wibbleStateFlatMapper(k: String,
                            it: Iterator[Wibble],
                            state: GroupState[WibbleState]): Iterator[Wibble] = it

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("PartialModelization")
      .master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    // imagine this is actually a streaming data frame
    val input = spark.createDataFrame(List(("a", 1, 0), ("b", 1, 2)))
      .toDF("x", "y", "z")
    // dont want to model z in the case class
    // if that seems pointless imagine there is also z1, z2, z3, etc
    // or that z is itself a struct

    input.select($"x", $"y", struct("*").as("data"))
      .as[Wibble]
      .groupByKey(w => w.x)
      .flatMapGroupsWithState[WibbleState, Wibble](
        OutputMode.Append, GroupStateTimeout.NoTimeout)(wibbleStateFlatMapper)
      .select("data.*")
      .show()

  }

}
```

Which gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for org.apache.spark.sql.Row
- field (class: "org.apache.spark.sql.Row", name: "data")
- root class: "com.example.so.Wibble"
```

Conceptually you might suggest trying to find some key that allows us to join to output dataframe with the input one to recover the "data" attribute but that just seems from performance and implementation complexity stand point to be a horrible solution. (I'd rather just type out the whole data structure in my case classes in that case!)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found so far is to use a tuple to seperate mapper data and row data.

So we remove the data attribute from `Wibble`.

```
case class Wibble
(
  x: String,
  y: Int
)
```

Modify the types on our stateful flat mapper to handle `(Wibble, Row)` instead of just `Wibble`:

```
def wibbleStateFlatMapper(k: String,
                          it: Iterator[(Wibble, Row)],
                          state: GroupState[WibbleState]): Iterator[(Wibble, Row)] = it
```

Now our pipeline code becomes:

```
// imagine this is actually a streaming data frame
val input = spark.createDataFrame(List(("a", 1, 0), ("b", 1, 2)))
  .toDF("x", "y", "z")

val inputEncoder = RowEncoder(input.schema)
val wibbleEncoder = Encoders.product[Wibble]
implicit val tupleEncoder = Encoders.tuple(wibbleEncoder, inputEncoder)

input.select(struct($"x", $"y").as("wibble"), struct("*").as("data"))
  .as(tupleEncoder)
  .groupByKey({case (w,_) => w.x})
  .flatMapGroupsWithState(
    OutputMode.Append, GroupStateTimeout.NoTimeout)(wibbleStateFlatMapper)
  .select("_2.*")
  .show()
```